# How can I set selector just click the button?

Tags: android, android-selector

I hve searched many times but I did not find what i need.

### What i need is :

when a user just click the button I want it changed the background image.(user does not need press to the button I need just one click and change the image )

### what i did is :

**in selector:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:state_pressed="true" 
        android:drawable="@drawable/web_wl" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/web" />
</selector>
```

**and in button xml :**

```
  <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_wb"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"  
        android:background="@drawable/web_selector" />
```

but this works only a user hold his hand to the button, but I need it works just one click.

thanks in advance

Comment: Than you don't need a Button, use click-able views other than button, as button has a property to click down and return back to previous state.

Comment: thanks for answer, for example what can I use?

Comment: You can use any of the view like textview or layouts, make them clickable and apply your selector.

Comment: I did it textview and make it clickable but it does not working

Comment: can I use state_pressed ? or something else

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A selector uses the [Color State List Resource](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/color-list-resource.html). I'm not sure there is, in the list of states, the expected behaviour. However, you can achieve this with a click listener event instead of using a selector:

```
// init a boolean
private boolean isPressed = false; 

// click listener event 
btn_wb.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // change the background once 
        if(!isPressed) {
            v.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.web_wl);
            isPressed = true;
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: thank you for answer, but I use pageviewer, and how can I change the `setBackgroundResource` from the fragment , because the buttons on mainactivity?

Comment: I don't understand clearly @ErsinGülbahar. You have a ViewPager which uses Fragments but your button is on Activity, right? If not, could you explain a little more please.

Comment: Yes in my main activity I have button and I uses viewpager

Comment: Well @ErsinGülbahar, you need to update the background button from the activity... there is no need to do anything with fragments because your button is inside the activity. Just put the above snippet code inside onCreate method from activity.

Comment: ok it works just one thing I need , If a person use swipe how can I understand and set backround image? is there any method to detect which tab a person in?

Comment: @ErsinGülbahar, it might help you: [Getting the current position of a ViewPager](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8258759/getting-the-current-position-of-a-viewpager) and [ViewPager and Fragments Part II](http://tamsler.blogspot.fr/2011/11/android-viewpager-and-fragments-part-ii.html).