# OnPageChangeListener - how to get the id of the fragment I've just moved off of?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I have a `ViewPager` with several fragments using `FragmentStatePageAdapter`.

I'm looking to implement something that will allow me to send a string of data that is entered into an `EditText` from a `fragment` to an `activity` when the user swipes away from the fragment.

I've looked at `OnPageChangeListener` and tried a couple of different things with that but as `onPageSelected` gives you the `fragment id` of the one you're moving onto I can't get the `Layout View` of the `fragment` to reference the `EditText` I'm swiping away from. There will also be no set fragment that leads on to another i.e. `Fragment` 1 doesn't always lead to `Fragment` 2 etc.

I tried using the `onDestroy()` of the `fragment` but that doesn't seem to be called until I've swiped 2 `fragments` away so that's no use either.

Does anyone have any suggestions as to what I could use to achieve this?

Thanks

Comment: Are you using a FragmentStatePagerAdapter for your ViewPager? I imagine that class will have some kind of `getPosition()` function.

Comment: Relevant enough, but not sure if it's duplicate. Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8258759/getting-the-current-position-of-a-viewpager

Comment: @McAdam331 yes using a FragmentStatePagerAdapter. I can get the current position no problem when I'm on the fragment, I guess my issue is that I need to store this somewhere before the onPageSelected is called and then pass it through but without the user interacting with a button or such like. Does that make sense? Not sure I can use onAttach() or onResume() as to me it seems these will already have been invoked as part of the FragmentStateAdapters function, much as how the onDestroy doesn't get called until after 2 swipes?

Comment: Did you see the other post I linked to? Perhaps you can create a custom interface to track the last position/current position someone has visited?

Comment: @McAdam331 ah sorry hadn't saw that while I was typing out my ramble, will check it out thanks  :)

Comment: I've implemented the marked answer from your suggestion but it returns zero every time, likely something I'm doing wrong but puts me on the right track I think.

Answer (score 0):

Try remembering each fragment's id on each `onPageSelected()`. Once the fragment is selected, you remember its id. Once the other one is selected, you check the remembered id just before you update it.

Comment: can you expand on this a bit more? At what point will you remember the fragment and would you use the viewpager.getcurrentitem() >